# Excel to count number of concurrent sessions based on start/end times

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a massive set of data that I'm trying to work through.  In Column A, I have a username, in Column B I have a session start date/time, in Column C I have the session end date/time.

I am trying to count how many concurrent sessions are on going at any one time based on the user account.  The tough spot that I'm running into is that one user could have multiple sessions going on at one time.

For example:

```
User     Start Time               End Time            Desired Result (license count)

JW      03/24/2015 14:00:44      03/24/2015 14:09:57     -->    4
TT      03/24/2015 13:58:14      03/24/2015 14:21:08     -->    3
DQ      03/24/2015 13:53:10      03/24/2015 14:15:39     -->    3
BB      03/24/2015 13:50:55      03/24/2015 14:20:42     -->    2
BA      03/24/2015 13:43:02      03/24/2015 13:57:26     -->    2
JW      03/24/2015 13:40:30      03/24/2015 13:48:38     -->    1
BA      03/24/2015 13:18:26      03/24/2015 13:18:44     -->    1
BA      03/24/2015 13:15:18      03/24/2015 13:15:22     -->    1
CT      03/24/2015 11:56:55      03/24/2015 11:58:21     -->    1
CT      03/24/2015 11:53:23      03/24/2015 11:56:55     -->    1
CT      03/24/2015 11:51:50      03/24/2015 11:53:23     -->    1
CT      03/24/2015 11:48:11      03/24/2015 12:16:36     -->    1
CT      03/24/2015 11:36:54      03/24/2015 11:37:50     -->    1
CT      03/24/2015 11:33:52      03/24/2015 11:39:38     -->    1
CT      03/24/2015 11:31:25      03/24/2015 11:34:01     -->    1
```

The fourth column shows the result that I want to be able to compute
with a formula.  The above data can be shown graphically as:

[image: bar chart]

As you can see at the end of the example (and the bottom of the chart),
user CT has multiple sessions going at one time. 
Those connections would count as only one license.

Let me know if I need to clarify this.

Comment: Perhaps you could just give your expected results for that small dataset so that we know what we're aiming for?

Comment: So you're trying to count concurrent sessions by different users?  Time is continuous.  How do you want to count and report?  Would this be like a timeline, where a changing number of concurrent sessions triggers an entry for that start time?  Is the data all in reverse chronological sequence?

Comment: Yes we are trying to count concurrent sessions by users.  I would like to count by username and then report back when each session starts, how many other different concurrnent users have a session open at the same time.  The data is all in reverse chronological sequence.

Comment: Not sure how to get a screen shot of the expected results into the comments here so feel free to advise. :)

The expected license count for the above example would be as follows:
4
3
3
2
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

The initiation of a new session would be the trigger to recalculate the license usage count.

Comment: @user439742: FYI, you need to address comments like I did here or nobody will be aware of your posting.  Your comments are confusing.  If concurrent sessions for the same user counts as 1, counting by user will produce all 1's, unless you're just talking about consolidating the data in preparation for analysis.  Different users don't start and end at the same time.  When a session ends, does that also trigger an event where the count decreases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your data is in columns `A` to `C`, starting at row 2 then you can use this "array formula" in `D2`

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B$2:B$16<=B2,IF(C$2:C$16>=B2,MATCH(A$2:A$16,A$2:A$16,0))),ROW(A$2:A$16)-ROW(A$2)+1),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down the column

**Explanation:**

This is a common technique used to get a count of different values in one column (in this case users) where some criteria are met in other columns (in this case that the latest start time/date is between the start time/date and end time/date in other columns).

The "data array" for `FREQUENCY` is the result of the `MATCH` function for the rows where the time criteria are met - and `MATCH` will find the **first** matching value, so where you have repeat users `MATCH` returns the same number for each (and you get `FALSE` for rows where conditions are not met)

The `FREQUENCY` "bins" consist of all the possible results for `MATCH` (1 to 15 in this case), so if the conditions (that the time band contains the latest start time) are met and the user is the same, the **same number** is returned in the data array and it goes in the same `bin`......**so it's sufficient to count the number of bins which are >0 to get a count of different users.**

Specifically for row 2, for example, the data array becomes this:

`{1;2;3;4;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}`

and the 4 different values are returned to 4 different bins so you get a result of 4

....but for row 10 the data array becomes this:

`{FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;9;9;FALSE;9;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}`

where there are 3 rows that match the time conditions.....but all for the same user (`CT`), so the `MATCH` function returns 9 (the position of the first "CT" entry in `A2:A16`) for all three, so then `FREQUENCY` gets 3 values in the same bin, so the formula resolves to this:

`=SUM(IF({0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0},1))`

The `IF` function returns a 1 for every non-zero value in the array returned by `FREQUENCY` and `SUM` sums those 1s.....but there's only one non-zero value so the result is `1` (representing the number of different users with sessions open at that time)

See screenshot attached

[image]

Comment: You get the results asked for in the OP's comment, so this obviously works.  Can you expand your answer a little to explain how it works?  That would help people apply this to other problems.  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 - no problem, I added an explanation

Comment: Nice explanation.

Comment: Thanks Barry - great explanation and was exactly what I was looking for.  Only took ~45 minutes for Excel to process my 20,000+ rows.

Comment: Are you referring to all 20,000 rows in all the formulas? Depending on your data you may be able to speed it up by using smaller ranges - if the data is sorted by time then presumably there will only be at most a few hundred rows which can overlap with the current row?

Comment: Yes I had ~20,000 rows worth of data that I had to expand your formula omtp.  (18 months worth of ~25 folks connecting to various machines).  Once I expanded, it began crunching away.  Very useful info us to have.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a much shorter, simpler formula that produces the desired result,
which seems to be

- the number of rows below this one for which

  - the time ranges overlap, and
  - the user is different
- plus one.

The first step is to figure out that
interval Start<sub>1</sub>/End<sub>1</sub>
overlaps interval Start<sub>2</sub>/End<sub>2</sub>
if and only if Start<sub>1</sub> < End<sub>2</sub>
and End<sub>1</sub> > Start<sub>2</sub>. 
(This is easy to see if you think about it; easier if you draw it.)

[barry houdini used ≤ and ≥](https://superuser.com/q/904265/354511#904352), so I’ll use the same convention. 
AFAICT, there are no instances in the example dataset
where the start or end time of one session exactly coincides
with the start or end time of a session belonging to a different user,
so this difference in approach should not yield different results
(for the example dataset).

So, for each row, we want to count the rows below this one
in the start/end record for which the above is true,
and the User ID does not equal the User ID for this row. 
And add 1.  That is simply

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B$16, "<="&C2, C2:C$16, ">="&B2, A2:A$16, "<>"&A2) + 1
```

Note that I defined my ranges to go from the current row
(represented as Row 2, containing cells `A2`, `B2` and `C2`)
to absolute row number 16
(represented as Row $16, containing cells `A16`, `B16` and `C16`). 
This causes the `COUNTIF` to look in
only the current row and the following ones. 
And note that this is ***not*** an array formula.

I would post a screenshot,
but it would be (effectively) identical to barry’s,
and hence a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: Disclosure: this is an adaptation of my recent answer to [Using Excel to count number of concurrent sessions based on start/end times and PC Name](http://superuser.com/q/1096785/150988).

Comment: FOR ANYONE STILL COMING HERE IN 2021+ AFTER A CONCURRENT CALL GOOGLE SEARCH:

I used this but it gave me the same results as =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$10000,"<="&C2,$C$2:$C$10000,">="&B2)-1

This just shows me overlapping calls, not concurrent. I have a call that started at 12:19:27 and ends at 13:16:32, this overlapped with 11 other calls but during this period the maximum concurrent was 4 calls. Barry Houdini's formula grabbed the correct concurrent. I didn't actually have a unique user field to match against so I just used the start time as I'm not sure how to update that without breaking it.

Comment: @Accendi: If you're saying that there's an issue with my answer, please explain it more clearly. If you have a question that isn't answered here, feel free to post it as a new question. Please @-ping us so we know to look at it. Be sure to explain the difference between ''overlapping'' and ''concurrent''.