# Excel to count number of concurrent sessions based on start/end times and PC Name

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know there is a very similar thread to the this one already –
[Excel to count number of concurrent sessions based on start/end times](https://superuser.com/questions/904265/excel-to-count-number-of-concurrent-sessions-based-on-start-end-times) –
however, as much as I try,
I am unable to replicate and manipulate the suggested answer to meet my needs.

I am also looking to detect when a user ID is logged onto a legacy unix ERP system from multiple PCs simultaneously – potentially they’re sharing their credentials with a colleague.

An example of the data is:

```
Record #    Time In    Time Out    User      PC Name
1           10:54      10:55       Al        PC1
2           10:55      16:55       Dave      PC42
3           09:11      09:29       Al        PC1
4           11:02      18:03       Al        PC1
5           16:19      17:38       George    PC678
6           16:43      17:41       Al        PC678
7           16:46      17:39       Dave      PC42
8           17:25      17:49       Al        PC42
```

The “Time In” and “Time Out” values are actually full date/times,
so you don’t need to worry about comparing events
that happened on different days.  I am displaying only the times here
so as to avoid providing **Too Much Information**. 
The above data can be shown graphically as:

[image: bar chart]

Towards the end of the list (and the bottom of the chart)
you can see that user Al is accessing the system from multiple PCs
at the same time,
as well as the other users also accessing the system from the same PCs.
User Al is either walking round and logging in (unlikely)
or the other users are able to log in as Al
in order to perform tasks their permissions do not allow them to do.
Ideally I'd like to have a new column to highlight that at that time
there were concurrent sessions from User ID Al on different PCs.
Record # 4, 6 and 8 would alert –
Record # 2 and 7 are OK as the same user logged in on the same PC.

Comment: Your data are flawed: (1) DEF is logged in to PC345 for two ***overlapping*** time periods (rows 2 and 7), (2) ABC and DEF are logged in to PC345 ***concurrently*** (rows 2 and 8), and (3) ABC and GHI are logged in to PC456 ***concurrently*** (rows 5 and 6). If it’s possible and valid for a user to be logged to a single PC for ***overlapping*** time periods (i.e., he logs in, then he logs in again, and then he logs out, and later logs out again) please explain more clearly how your data work and what results you want. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  As if your raw data weren’t hard enough to understand, you then say that you want rows 4, 6 and 6 flagged. 4, ***6** and **6**!*  (I guess you mean 4, 6 and ***8**?*)  Also, it might not matter in this case, but it’s conventional, when asking a question about Excel, to say what version of Excel you are using.  Please do not respond in comments; if you choose to make your question clearer and more complete, [edit] it.

Comment: Your data hurt my eyes.  I’ve changed them in a trivial way to be more eye-friendly.  (By the way, is that meant to be `yy/mm/dd` format, or is it `dd/mm/yy`?)

Comment: Thanks all for the posts. Sorry it wasn't explained very well and my raw data was somewhat difficult to read (first post so still learning). Date format was dd/mm/yy.  Just to confirm this is the log file from a legacy unix system running -  so it would be possible to open two sessions as Per Dave in row#7 from the same PC or node( a user is free to open as many sessions as they want - I know poor design). We have a fix to prevent user opening multiple sessions from their own pc and most importantly having two sessions open with their credentials on different nodes  - I've been asked to....

Comment: analyse the data so we can identify users who do login from multiple nodes and understand their need to do it - e.g. are their permissions wrong?

Comment: OK, I’ve extended my answer to handle (i.e., ignore) cases where a user has concurrent sessions on the same PC. Please let me know whether it solves your problem and gives you the information that you need. If it doesn’t, why/how not?  What can I do to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to identify any rows
for which there is at least one other row with the same User ID
for which the In/Out time ranges overlap. 
This is fairly straightforward (at least, once you know the answer. 
The first step is to figure out that
interval Start<sub>1</sub>/End<sub>1</sub>
overlaps interval Start<sub>2</sub>/End<sub>2</sub>
if and only if Start<sub>1</sub> < End<sub>2</sub>
and End<sub>1</sub> > Start<sub>2</sub>. 
(This is easy to see if you think about it; easier if you draw it.) 
So, for each row, we want to count the rows in the login/logout record
for which the above is true,
and the User ID equals the User ID for this row.  That is simply

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$9, "<"&B2, B$2:B$9, ">"&A2, C$2:C$9, "="&C2)
```

for your original data layout
(where **Time In** is Column `A`, **Time Out** is Column `B`,
and **User** is Column `C`). 
This will evaluate to a minimum of 1, because every row overlaps itself. 
You want to see which rows overlap *other* rows, so we do

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$9, "<"&C2, C$2:C$9, ">"&B2, D$2:D$9, "="&D2) > 1,  "Overlap",  "")
```

Once I change the **Time In** for Record #7 (User Dave on PC42)
from 16:46 to 16:56
to eliminate the overlap with Record #2 (***also*** User Dave on PC42),
which I presume was unintentional, I get the following results:

[image: spreadsheet]

which, I believe, are what you want.

OK, if it’s possible and valid
for a user to be logged to a single PC for overlapping time periods
(as Dave does on PC42 in records 2 and 7),
and you don’t want these to be counted as overlaps,
then we need to modify our formula to count only rows
where the PC is different:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$9, "<"&B2, B$2:B$9, ">"&A2, C$2:C$9, "="&C2, D$2:D$9, "<>"&D2) > 0, "Overlap", "")
```

Note that we have to change the test from `> 1` to `> 0`
because rows no longer overlap themselves.

Comment: By the way, I don’t understand that other question either.  Luckily, I *believe* that I (mostly) understand this one.

Comment: Thanks all for the posts. Sorry it wasn't explained very well and my raw data was somewhat difficult to read (first post so still learning).