# Excel - Max number of concurrent projects based on start and end date overlaps

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table with 3 columns:

- Project Name
- Start Date (dd/mm/yyyy)
- End Date (dd/mm/yyyy)

How can I get a count of the max number of projects going on at any one time?

Comment: (1) I believe that I understand your problem, but we much prefer questions that show some sample data (input and expected result).  (2) It probably doesn’t matter, but you should say what version of Excel you are using.  (3) See [this](https://superuser.com/q/904265/150988 "Excel to count number of concurrent sessions based on start/end times") and [this](https://superuser.com/q/1096785/150988 "Excel to count number of concurrent sessions based on start/end times and PC Name").  (4) Please make an effort to solve this yourself (using the above references) and tell us what happened.

Answer (score -1):

Depending how you want to display this

**Total By Fixed Date**

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$7, "<="&E2,$C$2:$C$7,">="&E2)
```

**Total By Current Date**

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$7, "<="&TODAY(),$C$2:$C$7,">="&TODAY())
```

[image]